# Error Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-20.04, mariadb-10.5

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.4 database server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
         └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-29 00:21:20 KST; 7s ago
Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
      https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
Process: 56679 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 56681 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 56684 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 56732 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 56732 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info mariadbd[56732]: 2020-06-29  0:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info mariadbd[56732]: 2020-06-29  0:21:20 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info mariadbd[56732]: 2020-06-29  0:21:20 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info mariadbd[56732]: 2020-06-29  0:21:20 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info mariadbd[56732]: 2020-06-29  0:21:20 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info mariadbd[56732]: 2020-06-29  0:21:20 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info mariadbd[56732]: 2020-06-29  0:21:20 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 29 00:21:20 gjan.info systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.4 database server.
```

Some error occured when start mariadb service.
I try some command likes
1.

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile101
rm /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
```

2. 

```
rm -R /var/lib/mysql/*
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

but return same error.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: You're using MariaDB, not MySQL. I removed the [tag:mysql] tag.

Comment: thanks Bill Karwin I will edit it

Comment: @KangDoYeoung it's better to move directories than to delete them right away as you may need the date later

Comment: Deleting files is never a good way to do recovery.  Look at more of the error log `journalctl -u mariadb.service -n 30` and there might be more information as to the cause.